# Need to align text that is being populated into a column - can't use text-align or float

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to move my text to a specific space within a column that I'm not able to do using text-align in CSS. We are building an app that populates a price when a quantity is selected. Please see below for a screenshot:

[image]

I need the $14 under Item Total to be centered but don't know how else to do it. I have tried float: center; as well. I think the real issue is that I need it in a specific place that isn't necessarily right, left or center. Is there a way to specify exactly where I want to have that number populate?

Here is a snippet of the HTML - the relevant class is bold:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="img/feed.png">

    <title>Feed.me</title>
</head>
<body>

      <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
             <h1>Feed.me</h1>
          <img src="img/hat.png" id ="image1"></img>
          <img src="img/ware.png" id="image2"></img>

      </nav>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-center">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-center">
        <center>Customer Name: <input class="customerName" type="text" placeholder="" /></center>
        <br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BEGIN RESTAURANT LIST -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-center">
                <div class="list-group-item rest">Tacolicious</div>
                    <!-- <div class="row"> -->
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-center">
                            <table class="table table-hover menu taco">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">Item Name</th>
                                        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">Price</th>
                                        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">Quantity</th>
                                        <th class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">Item Total</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="menu-item-1">
                                        <td>Grilled Squid Veracruz</td>
                                        <td>$14</td>
                                        <td><input class="form" placeholder="0" data-price="14" type="number" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" max="99"></td>
                                        **<td class="price1 itemTotal"></td>**
```

In the CSS, I have this for .itemTotal:

```
.itemTotal{

    text-align: center;
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no `float:center`. Why can't you use text-align?

Comment: dollar amounts should be right justified.  Consider displaying ".00" for zero cents as well.

Comment: show us some html and css please.

Comment: the text-align doesn't put it quite under the "Item Total" like I would like it to be. Ideally, I'd like the $14 to be directly underneath it (e.g. between the m and the T). I am adding some code now for everyone to look at. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Have you tried table cell and align properties?

Comment: @Aibrean I am looking to do it in a CSS selector instead of going through each table because I would need to go through 64 tables to add the code :(

Comment: you could target it via CSS selectors (assuming that the price is always in the second field) like this `table tr td:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try absolute positioning.

Here is a fiddle with two examples of how you could use it: http://jsfiddle.net/Pzw8w/1/

The first table in the fiddle uses a new class `scooch` on the `<td>` wrapping the $14 you're hoping to scooch (hehe). The second table uses a new wrapper element, a `<span class="scooch">`. If you can, I would suggest using the second option, because it'll be more reliable on any row in your table (not just the first row). Hope that helps!

Comment: It looks like I am getting closer but now I have two .itemTotals appearing on the page - one in the regular place and then one wherever I specify the pixels. Do you know how I might fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved my problem using the text-indent property specifying the number of pixels I need to use to put the .itemTotal in the right place. Please see below for an example:

```
.itemTotal{
    text-indent: 50px;
}
```

Thanks everyone for your input!